# Парсинг WORD-документов

Tags: c#, .net, interop

В общем, есть Word-документы формата *.doc.
В этих Word-документах есть чередования таблиц и текста.

Мне нужно идти сверху вниз документа и если я встречаю простой текст, то делаю одно действие, если таблицу, то что-то другое.

С Word-ом никогда не работал. Можно ли какой-нибудь простой пример работы с Word'ом?

Пока нашел, что к таблицам я могу достучаться через свойства `Tables`, но это не интересно, так как чередование таблиц и текста мне важно.

Comment: Простой пример вряд ли найдётся. Боюсь, вам нужен Office Interop. Распарсить Word'овский документр вручную бесперспективно.

Comment: @VladD, да, я знаю, что меня ждет эта страшная вещь...

Comment: Переформатировать в docx и там уже работать с помощью OpenXML

Comment: @Сергей, какой либой удобно с DOCX работать  ?

Comment: https://www.nuget.org/packages/DocumentFormat.OpenXml/

Answer (score 1):

Приведу пример, как я парсил doc на js. На с# не переписывал. Писал давно.

```
var fs = new ActiveXObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject");

function doc2txt(afile){    
var z,d,f, dd, content;
content = "";
afile = afile.toLowerCase();
if (afile.indexOf('.')<0) return;
if (afile.charAt(0)=='~') return;
if (afile.indexOf('.doc')>0)  { /*  Расшифровка DOC файла */
  //var f = fs.OpenTextFile("курс валют_01.02.11.doc");
  f = fs.OpenTextFile(afile,1,0,-1); // открываем файл как юникод    
  d = f.Read(0xA00 / 2);  // Пропустить заголовок
while (1) {    
  try {   d = f.Read(256); } catch (e) { return content;}; // читаем блок
  dd = d.substring(0,1);
  dd = escape(dd);
  dd = dd.replace("%u","");
  try {
   dd = eval("0x" + dd); // получаем значение первого двойного слова
   } catch(e) { dd = 0;};
 // Проверяем первое двойное слово на "мусор" и служебные
  if (dd == 0x14AA) return content;  
  if (dd > 7000) return content;
  if ((dd & 0xFF00) == 0x600) continue;
  if ((dd & 0xFF00) == 0x800) continue;
  if ((dd & 0xFF00) == 0x900) continue;
  if ((dd & 0xFF00) == 0xA00) continue;
  if ((dd & 0xFF00) == 0xC00) continue;
  if ((dd & 0xFF00) == 0xE00) continue;
  // далее преобразовуем "нечитабельный" текст
  d = areplace(d,unescape("%00"),"");
  d = areplace(d,unescape("%08"),"|");// Преобразование для таблицы \t в |
  d = escape(d);
  d = areplace(d,"%07","|"); // Преобразование для таблицы
  d =  areplace(d,"%uFFFF","");
  d =  areplace(d,escape(","),",");   d =  areplace(d,escape("."),".");
  d =  areplace(d,"%0A",""); // убираю \r
  d = unescape(d);
  //content +=  "hdr="+ dd+ ";" +  d;
content += d; // добавляем в копилку обработаный текст.
//  WScript.Echo(dd + " = " + d);
}
}
}



function areplace(a,b,c){
   var i;    
   while (1){
     i = a.length;
     a = a.replace(b,c);
     if (a.length==i) break;
     };
    return a;
  };
```

После обработки, в таблицах разделитель `\t`, так же есть разделитель линий. Служебную информацию не видно, данные отдаёт как понятный текст.

Код работает под виндой. В кратце - doc-файл представляет собой biff-файл, т.е. небольшую "файловую" систему. 512-байт (0xA00) идет заголовок. Далее идут секции по 4096 байт. Один из "файлов" в системе содержит поток doc-документа, который разбит на секции по 512 байт. Если идет читабельный текст - то он внутри секции 512 байт. Текст хранится в юникоде.

Answer (score 0):

Вроде, костыльно и методом тыка нарисовал такого монстра:

```
    for (var parIdx = 1; parIdx <= doc.Paragraphs.Count; parIdx++)
    {
        Paragraph paragraph = doc.Paragraphs[parIdx];
        if (paragraph.Range.Tables.Count > 0)//Параграф является таблицей, если таблиц>0
        {
            foreach (Table table in paragraph.Range.Tables)
            {
                parIdx += table.Range.Paragraphs.Count;//делаем смещение на кол-во параграфов, которые задействованы в таблице
                for (int i = 1; i <= table.Rows.Count; i++)
                {
                    var res = String.Empty;
                    Row row = table.Rows[i];
                    for (var j = 1; j <= row.Cells.Count; j++)
                    {
                        var cell = row.Cells[j].Range.Text;
                        res += "|" + String.Join("", cell.Where(chr => !Char.IsControl(chr)));
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        else
        {
            var text = String.Join("", paragraph.Range.Text.Where(chr => !Char.IsControl(chr)));
            Console.WriteLine($"TEXT:{text}");
        }
    }
```

Если у кого-то есть более красивый вариант, то предлагайте.